# Variable length row in a 2D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Hi I need to store rows of variable length in Matlab.. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) are what you want here.

Answer (score 4):

I realized the link in my comment wasn't necessarily clear enough for this kind of question, so I thought I'd expand it to an answer with an example.

Using a cell array, you can hold any data type in each cell.  Less generally, this means it works for holding vectors of different lengths, which is what you're asking for.

```
A = [0 1 2];
B = [3 4];

#% assigning a variable into a cell array:
C{1} = A;  #% note the curly braces {} instead of ()
C{2} = B;

#% getting a value out of a cell array:
D = C{2}; #% D is a 1x2 matrix of doubles
E = C(2); #% E is a 1x1 cell
```

As you can see, to access the elements of a cell array, use curly brackets `{}` instead of the usual parentheses `()`, both for reading from/writing to the cell array.